# SQL PHP joining 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

ive had a look about and just cant get my head around this.

The following is what im trying to achieve:

```
JobID AssignedTo SchDate ContractNo VisitNo Equipment SiteName SiteContact SiteAddress SiteTel AddedBy
1     Mark       220314  1          12      3500      Tesco    Joe         21 spooner  123455   Admin
```

When i use the following Query it some how creates 2 results when i should only have one:

```
SELECT j.JobID, j.CompletedBy, u.NameUser, j.SchDate, j.CustID, j.ContractNo, j.VisitNo,
s.EqName, si.SiteName, si.SiteContact, si.SiteAddress, si.SiteTele  
FROM jobs j, systypes s, users u, site si 
WHERE j.CompletedBy ='0' AND j.AssignedTo='$mytechname' AND j.SysTypeID=s.SysTypeID 
AND j.SiteID=si.SiteID
```

Here are the tables in working with:

**jobs**

```
JobID completedBy AssignedTo SchDate CustID ContractNo VisitNo SysTypeID SiteID AddedBy
1     0           1          220314  1      1          12      1         1      2
```

**site**

```
SiteID CustID SiteContact SiteName SiteAddress SiteTel
1      1      Ann Jones   Tesco    21 spooner  123455
2      2      John Hulson tele     54 vic st   443212
```

**systypes**

```
SysTypeID EqCode EqName
1         350    3500
2         450    4500
```

**users**

```
UserID NameUser UserName UserPass
1      Mark     mmc      1234
2      Admin    Admin    1234
```

I think i'm on the right tracks, i just need some guidance with this one.

If you have any questions please ask, thanks in advance.

**Results**

```
Count: 2 JobID: 1 CompletedBy: 0 AssignedTo: Mark McGuinness SchDate: 22/03/2014 CustID: 1 ContractNo: 12 VisitNo: 4 Equipment Name: 3500 SiteName: Tesco SiteContact: Ann Jones SiteAddress: 21 Good Street Glasgow G14 4CA SiteTele: 1413216545
Count: 2 JobID: 1 CompletedBy: 0 AssignedTo: Admin SchDate: 22/03/2014 CustID: 1 ContractNo: 12 VisitNo: 4 Equipment Name: 3500 SiteName: Tesco SiteContact: Ann Jones SiteAddress: 21 Good Street Glasgow G14 4CA SiteTele: 1413216545
```

Comment: 'j.SysTypeID=s.SysTypeID ' - you should replace with INNER JOIN

Comment: When i introduce the SiteID into the query thats what screws it up. When i display the output they are the same.

Comment: You should use modern join syntax, and specify join conditions for all 4 tables. Right now you're only doing one join, leaving the rest to be done as a cartesian.

Comment: Also, try selecting from 2 tables and see the result. Next, select from 3. And so on. Just an idea.

Comment: You are including `users` in the query, but you are not joining it other anything else.  Hence, the result set is multiplied by the number of rows in `users`.

Comment: did you cant use normal JOIN statement ?

Comment: I will be honest here... I'm not that fantastic at SQL, i have posted the results in the Edit. I have tried a Left Join but its all a little hazy to me. Could someone enlighten my situation (explain the difference or link me)

Comment: did you miss join condition with users table?

Comment: With regards with the users, it worked fine before i added in the site join. It was displaying 1 result with correct information.

Comment: Marc B can you explain a little? what join should i use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the basic query that should get you going

```
SELECT j.JobID, j.CompletedBy, u.NameUser, j.SchDate, j.CustID, 
   j.ContractNo, j.VisitNo,s.EqName, si.SiteName, si.SiteContact,
   si.SiteAddress, si.SiteTele  
FROM jobs as j
INNER JOIN users as u 
  ON j.AssignedTo = u.NameUser
INNER JOIN sites as si
  ON j.CustId = si.CustId
INNER JOIN systypes as s 
  ON j.SysTypeID  = s.SysTypeID
WHERE j.CompletedBy ='0' 
  AND j.AssignedTo='$mytechname'
```

A few pointers on that solution :

`INNER JOIN` : this command will add a row in your rowset only if the current row has a matching row in the joined table. If you want to include data even without matching row, go with `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`

Performance wise, you should use your `UserId` to make your join between the `users` and `jobs` table. By defaut to find the match MySQL fetch a limited number of bit data to find a matching key, using a string, you can fit less elements in each search iterations. When not using primary keys to make a join, make sure to create an index on your joined column

Finally, security wise, you should rely on [parametrized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of using your variables in your query string

Comment: j.*, s.*, st.*, u.* were used to simplify the query as it's not relevant to the specifics of the question

Comment: I have given you the answer due the explanation. There are another 2 working answers but you have enlightened me =) thanks.

Comment: up vote as removing the  the `j.*, s.*, st.*, u.*` values fixes the column collisions

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for.

```
SELECT j.JobID, j.CompletedBy, u.NameUser, j.SchDate, j.CustID, j.ContractNo, j.VisitNo,
s.EqName, si.SiteName, si.SiteContact, si.SiteAddress, si.SiteTele  
FROM jobs j
    INNER JOIN systypes s ON j.SysTypeID=s.SysTypeID
    INNER JOIN users u ON j.AssignedTo=u.UserID  AND u.NameUser='$mytechname' 
    INNER JOIN site si ON j.SiteID=si.SiteID
WHERE j.CompletedBy ='0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of column for user id in users table is UserId, try this query

```
SELECT j.JobID, j.CompletedBy, u.NameUser, j.SchDate, j.CustID, 
       j.ContractNo, j.VisitNo,s.EqName, si.SiteName, si.SiteContact,
       si.SiteAddress, si.SiteTele  
FROM jobs j, systypes s, users u, site si 
WHERE j.CompletedBy ='0' AND j.AssignedTo='$mytechname'
      AND j.SysTypeID=s.SysTypeID AND j.SiteID=si.SiteID 
      AND j.AssignedTo=u.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT j.JobID, j.CompletedBy, u.NameUser, j.SchDate, j.CustID, j.ContractNo, j.VisitNo,
s.EqName, si.SiteName, si.SiteContact, si.SiteAddress, si.SiteTele  
FROM jobs j, 
INNER JOIN 
     systypes s ON (s.SysTypeId = j.SysTypeId) 
INNER JOIN 
     users u ON (u.UserId = j.CustId), -- I'm assuming that CustId makes reference to tbl user 
INNER JOIN
     site si ON (si.SiteId = j.SiteId) 
WHERE j.CompletedBy ='0' AND j.AssignedTo='$mytechname'
```

Comment: u.userID is user information to login, the CustID is related to SiteID (each customer has a site) but ill see if this works, Thanks for the post Alan D.

Comment: This is not the correct answer as he is looking to output the Name of the person the job is assigned to so `INNER JOIN users u ON j.AssignedTo=u.UserID`

Comment: Yeah this didnt work =[ gonna try another post, thanks anyways dude =)